# JMeter - How to change File Upload path after X seconds

Tags: jmeter

As the title suggests, I am trying to figure out how to change the File Upload path in JMeter after X amount of seconds. I need this since I am testing an API that uses 60 files and I need to cycle through each file every minute. I already have an idea of using CSV Data Set Config but I'm not sure if that will change the File Path every minute like I need it to. Or maybe even read from the CSV file once per minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to read the path to the file from a JMeter Property `path`

   ```
   ${__P(path,)}
   ```

   [image]
2. Add another [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan and use a [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) in combination with CSV Data Set Config to read the next filename from the CSV file into `path` JMeter Variable

   [image]
3. Add a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler to introduce 60 seconds of sleep between iterations

   [image]
4. And finally add a JSR223 PostProcessor to convert `path` variable into `path` property:

   ```
   props.put('path', vars.get('path'))
   ```

   [image]

   see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article to learn what do these `props` and `vars` shorthands mean
5. That's it, Debug Sampler will be executed each 60 seconds, the CSV Data Set Config will read next value from the CSV file and the JSR223 PostProcessor will update the `path` property value with the new filename or file path.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and it solved my problem, I thought I was gonna have to put some sort of delay in my actual thread group but this is much better